# Huggingface datasets map n inputs to m outputs crash pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid

Tags: python, python-3.x, huggingface-datasets

I am running it this problem while using the `datasets` library from huggingface. From the docs I see that mapping your input of n sample to an output of m samples should be possible.

> If batched is True and batch_size is n > 1, then the function takes a batch of n examples as input and can return a batch with n examples, or with an arbitrary number of examples. Note that the last batch may have less than n examples. A batch is a dictionary, e.g. a batch of n examples is {“text”: [“Hello there !”] * n}

In my case I am loading images from disk and some of the images are corrupt and should be kicked out. So `n` is bigger then `m`.

Any hints, comments or help is appreciated.

Here a small examples that should reproduce the error.

```py
from datasets import Dataset
import pandas as pd

dataset_ = Dataset.from_pandas(
    pd.DataFrame({
        'path': ['doc1.jpg', 'doc2.jpg', 'doc3.jpg'], 
        'documentType': [1,2,3] })
)

def fun_map(examples):
    return {"output": [1,2]}

preprocessed_dataset = dataset_.map(fun_map, batched=True, batch_size=2, num_proc=2)
```

The `datasets` version is `2.5.2` and produces this output:

```
#0: 100%|███████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████████| 1/1 [00:00<00:00, 328.40ba/s]
#1:   0%|                                                                                                                                                                | 0/1 [00:00<?, ?ba/s]
multiprocess.pool.RemoteTraceback:                                                                                                                                       | 0/1 [00:00<?, ?ba/s]
"""
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/multiprocess/pool.py", line 125, in worker
    result = (True, func(*args, **kwds))
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/datasets/arrow_dataset.py", line 578, in wrapper
    out: Union["Dataset", "DatasetDict"] = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/datasets/arrow_dataset.py", line 545, in wrapper
    out: Union["Dataset", "DatasetDict"] = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/datasets/fingerprint.py", line 480, in wrapper
    out = func(self, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/datasets/arrow_dataset.py", line 2867, in _map_single
    writer.write_batch(batch)
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/datasets/arrow_writer.py", line 527, in write_batch
    pa_table = pa.Table.from_arrays(arrays, schema=schema)
  File "pyarrow/table.pxi", line 3597, in pyarrow.lib.Table.from_arrays
  File "pyarrow/table.pxi", line 2793, in pyarrow.lib.Table.validate
  File "pyarrow/error.pxi", line 100, in pyarrow.lib.check_status
pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: Column 2 named output expected length 1 but got length 2
"""

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/datasets/arrow_dataset.py", line 2563, in map
    transformed_shards[index] = async_result.get()
  File "/opt/conda/lib/python3.8/site-packages/multiprocess/pool.py", line 771, in get
    raise self._value
pyarrow.lib.ArrowInvalid: Column 2 named output expected length 1 but got length 2
```

**Update**

The huggingface documentation has the answer at: https://huggingface.co/docs/datasets/about_map_batch.

In the case when you produce a bigger or smaller output, then you need to remove all the columns.

```py
preprocessed_dataset = dataset_.map(fun_map, batched=True, batch_size=2, num_proc=2, remove_columns=dataset_.column_names)
```